# How to MITM an http website without infiltrating any infrastructure?

Tags: web-application, man-in-the-middle

There's a certain website designed so that junior QAs learn to find bugs. Trouble is:

- it's `http://`
- there's no IP filtering
- users are very junior so they use their real names as user names and probably reuse their only password.

I do not intend to attack it nor do I have anything to gain from that; furthermore I've informed the owner of the security flaws - this should put Your moral compass at rest.

Imagine I want to attack it, but I am reluctant to exploit vulnerabilities of the server, router or ISP for fear of being legally liable. Nor am I on the same LAN. Can the traffic be somehow observed remotely?

Comment: The first half of this question seems utterly irrelevant....

Comment: In order to MITM ... you need to be ... in the middle.

Comment: Why do you want to attack ***someone else's*** connection to the server? Why not just intercept your own connection?

Answer (score 1):

For training purposes you can take some VMs at some cloud provider, organize them into an internal network, so that the whole traffic remains within this network. Then you can do there whatever you want within this network. If you need it repeatedly, take tools like Terraform, so that every time after executing the scripts you get identical environment. After training you can delete it and next time re-create exactly the same one. It is much easier and much more secure than disabling some real security measures in your real network.